# Replicate the same JLabel with diferent variable names

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I'm needing to make the same `JLabel` appear multiple times on the same grid layout, but I'm having trouble implementing a method to produce `label00`, `label01`, `label02`, ..., `label10`. These labels must have the same content. Can someone give me a code example to do this?

```
public class Grid {
    private JFrame f;

    public Grid(String fname, int row, int column, int d) {
        f = new JFrame(fname);
        f.setLayout(new GridLayout(row,column));
        f.setSize(row*d,column*d);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addContent(row,column,d);
    }

    public void open() {
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addContent(int r, int c, int d) {
        JLabel label=new JLabel(" ");
        Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 2);
        label.setBorder(border);
        label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(d,d));
        f.add(label);
        JLabel label1= new JLabel("1 ");
        f.add(label1);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Grid grid = new Grid("Test", 5, 4, 50);
         grid.open();
    }
}
```

Instead of creating each label manually I want to implement a method to generate `label1`, `label2`, ... `labeli` automatically with the text of the original label.

Comment: What do you mean by "nametag"? The label's text?

Comment: by name tag I mean the label1 of JLabel label 1=new JLabel" ";

Comment: They're not "nametags", they're variable names. I recommend [a beginners tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) that shows you how to work with variables, arrays, lists etc.

Comment: Sorry, it's still not clear what you're asking. If you want multiple JLabels, you should look at *"arrays"* e.g. `JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[30]` will give you 30 labels. Then you can use *"for loops"* to iterate over all of your labels. Each label will be `null` by default, so be careful

Comment: Edited the post maybe, its clearer now

Comment: "basically the same label", no they're not. they're different instances of JLabel.

Comment: the same content, I wanna have empty grids so in each grid space I wanna have " " so I can make a grid with r rows and c columns with empty spaces

Comment: Ah! The [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why do you want an empty grid?

Comment: To make a tic tac toe game

Comment: @Abra o didn't because its a five steps exercise and the tictactoe game is the last one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a grid which is a two dimensionnal array. To fill it with `JLabel`, iterate over the two dimensions and add your custom `JLabel` like this. If you have specific properties, like computation on values or styling, I suggest you create a custom `JLabel`.

```
private JFrame f;
public Grid(String fname, int row, int column, int d) {
    f = new JFrame(fname);
    f.setLayout(new GridLayout(row,column));
    f.setSize(row*d,column*d);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    addContent(row,column,d);
}

public void open() {
    f.setVisible(true);
}

private void addContent(int r, int c, int d) {
    Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 2);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < r ; i++) {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < c ; j++) {
            f.add(new JLabel(i+","+j) {{
                 setBorder(border);
                 setPreferredSize(new Dimension(d,d));
            }});
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Grid grid = new Grid("Test", 5, 4, 50);
    grid.open();
}
```

Result :

[image: result]

**EDIT :**

Since it is a tic tac toe game and I suggested to you, create a custom JLabel which can implements mouselistener on click (for example), you will be able to modify colors and so on depending on events.

```
public class TicTacToeCell extends JLabel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public TicTacToeCell(Border border, int height, int width) {
        setText("");
        setBorder(border);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(height, width));
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (getText().isEmpty()) {
                    setText(getClickedValue());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You need to know what was the last click so put a static method to return O or X each time a cell has been clicked.

```
public static int clickValue = 0;
public static String getClickedValue() {
    clickValue = clickValue == 0 ? 1 : 0;
    return clickValue == 0 ? "X" : "O";
}
```

Add it to your grid when you build your GUI

```
private void addContent(int r, int c, int d) {
    Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 2);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < r ; i++) {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < c ; j++) {
            f.add(new TicTacToeCell(border, d, d));
        }
    }
}
```

Result (changed grid to 3,3) :

[image: result2]

Full example :

```
public class Grid {
    private JFrame f;
    public Grid(String fname, int row, int column, int d) {
        f = new JFrame(fname);
        f.setLayout(new GridLayout(row,column));
        f.setSize(row*d,column*d);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addContent(row,column,d);
    }
    public void open() {
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    private void addContent(int r, int c, int d) {
        Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 2);
        for (int i = 0 ; i < r ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0 ; j < c ; j++) {
                f.add(new TicTacToeCell(border, d, d));
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Grid grid = new Grid("Test", 3, 3, 50);
         grid.open();
    }
    public static int clickValue = 0;
    public static String getClickedValue() {
        clickValue = clickValue == 0 ? 1 : 0;
        return clickValue == 0 ? "X" : "O";
    }
    public class TicTacToeCell extends JLabel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public TicTacToeCell(Border border, int height, int width) {
            setText("");
            setBorder(border);
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(height, width));
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (getText().isEmpty()) {
                        setText(getClickedValue());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My objective is eventually to do a tic-tac-toe game, how can I have empty grids?

Comment: Layout manager [GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) does not honor preferred size of its contained components, so calling `setPreferredSize()` has no effect. Always a dilemma when answering questions. Do you simply correct the OP's code so that it runs, or do you write good code that solves his problem even if it has no resemblance to the code he posted in his question?

Comment: @Abra in this case i asked for code example, since i was having trouble understading how to reach the solution. Not going to just copy paste the code since that way i wouldn't learn anything. I Will go line by line analising and learning what it does and why. After that i Will able to reach a solution writing my own code

Comment: Also big up @Paul

Comment: @Abra One of the few good reasons I can see to extend a `JLabel` is for a component with a 1:1 (square) preferred size. It should use the larger size of width or height. Then to make is suitable for a game, center the text, set a large font and maybe some insets, then add it to the grid layout.

Comment: @gfaa 1) Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved. 2) There is actually no need to even keep the labels in an array. That is there is no need to know the name of the label variable. Instead, in the MouseListener you add to the label you just use the `getSource()` method of the MouseEvent to get the label that was clicked.